# C++ error: "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "(" token

Tags: c++, class, object

Having trouble at the start of this assignment.  Im sure it is a very basic error, hopefully a fresh pair of eyes can help.  I am getting the above code in my .cpp class file.  I have attached the .cpp and the header.  Error is in line 7 of the .cpp.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include "Encryptor.h"

Encryptor::Encryptor(){

}

Encryptor::Encryptor(key, plainText)
{
    newKey = key;
    newPlainText = plainText;

    cout << newKey << "/t" << newPlainText << endl;

}

Encryptor::~Encryptor()
{
    //dtor
}

/*string Encryptor::getEncryption(){

    return encryptedFile

}*/
```

header:

```
#ifndef ENCRYPTOR_H
#define ENCRYPTOR_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;


class Encryptor
{
    public:
        Encryptor();

        Encryptor(string, string);

        virtual ~Encryptor();

        //Accessor Function
        string getEncryption() const;


    private:
        string newKey;
        string newPlainText;
};

#endif // ENCRYPTOR_H
```

Comment: What is `Encryptor::Encryptor(key, plainText)`? Why no types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 7 should be:

```
Encryptor::Encryptor(string key, string plainText)
```

As you need to include types for the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You're not specifying the types for this constructor's definition

```
Encryptor::Encryptor(string key, string plainText)
                     ^^^^^^      ^^^^^^
{
    newKey = key;
    newPlainText = plainText;

    cout << newKey << "/t" << newPlainText << endl;
}
```

Furthermore this is not defined but just declared (as far as its definition stays commented out)

```
string getEncryption() const;
```

(and even that commented out definition lacks the `const` qualifier)

Comment: My skills are in electrical systems, not programming.  Thank you for understanding and I appreciate the help.